# Parse Quickstart error

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm new to Objective-C and to programming to be honest. Working on a bit of a project and have had the following returned when I try and use the Parse quickstart. Any suggestions?

> 2013-08-21 21:47:41.388 ParseStarterProject[3284:c07] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   'cannot setReadAccess for unsaved user'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x21f4012 0x1d27e7e 0x21f3deb 0x35057 0x3555d 0xaa33 0x32a5 0x2f76 0x3332 0xac5c 0x2e00 0xf761c7 0xf76232
>   0xec53d5 0xec5cc1 0x2636 0xe92157 0xe92747 0xe9394b 0xea4cb5 0xea5beb
>   0xe97698 0x214fdf9 0x214fad0 0x2169bf5 0x2169962 0x219abb6 0x2199f44
>   0x2199e1b 0xe9317a 0xe94ffc 0x2495 0x2395) libc++abi.dylib: terminate
>   called throwing an exception (lldb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Parse SDK is throwing an exception. From the error message, it looks like the problem is that you're sending `-setReadAccess` for an unsaved user. That makes sense -- it'd probably be difficult to read from an user object that hasn't yet been saved.

Comment: Thank you for that.  took out the -setReadAccess argument (sorry if not correct terminology) from appDelegate and it worked fine